# Refactoring suggestions?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I need some advice on how to refactor the code below. 
I have multiple configurations classes they are all different, but as you can see in the example code below there is a recurring pattern happening.

I was wondering what would be the best approach to simplify the View code?

```
    class IConfiguration1
   {
      public:

       virtual bool Save(const std::string& Output) = 0;        
       virtual bool OutText(const std::string& BaseFileName) = 0;    
       virtual bool Open() = 0;
   }

    class IConfiguration2
   {
       public:

        virtual bool Save(const std::string& Output) = 0;       
        virtual bool OutText(const std::string& BaseFileName) = 0;    
        virtual bool Update() = 0;
    }

    class MockConfiguration
    {
       MOCK_METHOD1(Save,bool(const std::string& Output));
       MOCK_METHOD1(OutText, bool(const std::string& BaseFileName));
    }   

    void View::SaveConfiguration1(std::string path)
    {
        m_Configuration1->Save(path);
        m_Configuration1->OutText(wxFileName::StripExtension(path).ToStdString())
        //Enable Reset Menu 
        wxMenuItem* item2 = GetMenuBar()->FindItem(wxID_RESET);
        if (item2 != NULL) item2->Enable(true);
    }

    void View::SaveConfiguration2(std::string path)
    {       
        m_Configuration2->Save(path);                                             
        m_Configuration2->OutText(wxFileName::StripExtension(path).ToStdString());

        //Enable Reset Menu 
        wxMenuItem* item2 = GetMenuBar()->FindItem(wxID_RESET);
        if (item2 != NULL) item2->Enable(true);
    }

    void View::SaveConfiguration3(std::string path)
    {
        m_Configuration3->Save(path);
        m_Configuration3->OutText(wxFileName::StripExtension(path).ToStdString());

        //Enable Reset Menu 
        wxMenuItem* item2 = GetMenuBar()->FindItem(wxID_RESET);
        if (item2 != NULL) item2->Enable(true);
    }
```

This is the function that calls the Save

```
void Controller::SaveCurrentSettings()
{
    switch (m_View->GetSelectedConfiguration())
    {
        case Options::Configuration1:
        {
            SaveConfiguration1();
        }
        break;

        case Options::Configuration2:
        {
            SaveConfiguration2();
        }
        break;

        case Options::Configuration3:
        {
            SaveConfiguration3();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: can you also explain the down vote? Should i delete this question or can it be transferred?

Comment: I'd say it's easier to delete.

Comment: `void View::SaveConfiguration(std::string path, Configuration& configuration)` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 I have different configuration definitions they aren't identical.

Comment: so `template <typename Conf> void View::SaveConfiguration(std::string path, Conf& configuration)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks. I will keep trying i get compiler errors with gmock when i use template parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an (abstract) interface that is common to all the configurations.
For the code shown this would include Save and OutText, but not Open or Update.

Derive the configurations from that interface

Replace the SaveConfiguration1, SaveConfiguration2 with a single function SaveConfiguration method that has an additional parameter to allow you to select the correct configuration to save. As Jarod42 comments, that parameter could be the configuration itself (passed as a reference to the new common interface I mention). Otherwise the parameter could be an enum which is used to select a configuration within the SaveConfiguration method.

Either way, by the time you reach the repeated Save and OutText lines, you would be calling them using via the new interface and relying on the power of virtual functions to deal with the fact that the different configuration are not identical by calling the specific versions of Save and OutText for you.

...Edit after comment "I already have an enum 1 level up"

So instead of:-

```
   case Options::Configuration1:
    {
        // your example call doesn't pass a view, but your SaveConfiguration requires one
        SaveConfiguration1(/* view? */);
    }
```

You could have

```
   case Options::Configuration1:
    {
        // your example call doesn't pass a view, but your SaveConfiguration requires one
        SaveConfiguration(/* view? */ , m_Configuration1);
    }
```

Where SaveConfiguration takes an IConfiguration&

```
void View::SaveConfiguration(std::string path, IConfiguration& config)           
{
    config.Save(path);
    config.OutText(wxFileName::StripExtension(path).ToStdString())
    //Enable Reset Menu 
    wxMenuItem* item2 = GetMenuBar()->FindItem(wxID_RESET);
    if (item2 != NULL) item2->Enable(true);
}



 class IConfiguration
 {
     public:

      virtual bool Save(const std::string& Output) = 0;        
      virtual bool OutText(const std::string& BaseFileName) = 0;    
      // no output or update
 }
```

You'd also need to choose between moving the switch into the view that owns the configurations or making the configurations available to the controller.

Comment: I already have an enum in the function one level up that determines which function gets called.